# Achieving consistent response times in GAE?

Tags: java, python, performance, google-app-engine, load-testing

When running load tests against my app I am seeing very consistent response times. Once there is a constant level of load on GAE, the mean reponse times get smaller and smaller. **But I want to have the same consistency on other apps that receive far fewer requests per second. In those I never need to support more than ~3 requests/second.**

**[Reading the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings#scheduler) makes me think increasing the number of minimum idle instances should result in more consistent response times**. But even then clients will still be see higher response times, every time GAE's scheduler thinks more instances are required. I am looking for a setup where users do not see those initial slow requests.

When I increase the number of minimum idle instances to 1, I want GAE to use the one resident instance only. As load increases, it should bring up and warm up new (dynamic) instances. [Only once they are warmed up](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances#Warmup_Requests), GAE should send requests to them. **But judging from the response times it seems as if client requests arrive in dynamic instances as they are brought up. As a result, those requests take a long time (up to 30 seconds).**

- **Could this happen if my warmup code is incomplete?**
- **Could the first calls on the dynamic instances be so slow because they involve code paths that have not been warmed up yet?**

I do not experience this problem during load tests or when enough people are using the app. But my testing environments practically unusable by clients when nobody is using the app yet e.g. in the morning.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some generic thoughts:

- 30 seconds startup-time for instances seems very much. We do a lot of initialization (including database-hits), and we have around 5 seconds overhead.
- Warmup-Requests aren't guaranteed. If all instances are busy, and the scheduler believes that the request will be answered faster if it starts a new instance instead of queuing it on a busy one, it will do so *without* wasting time with a warmup-request
- I don't think this is an issue of an cold code-path (though i don't know java's hotspot in detail), its probably the (mem-) cache which needs to fill first
- I don't know what you meant with "incomplete warmup code"; just check your logs for requests to /_ah/warmup - if there are any, warmup-requests are enabled and working.
- Increasing the amount of idle instances beyond the 1-instance mark probably won't help here.

Sadly, there aren't any generic tricks to avoid that, but you could try to

- defer initialization-code (doing only the absolute required minimum of instance-startup overhead)
- start a backend keeping the (mem-) cache hot

If you don't mind the costs (and don't need automatic scaling for your low-volume application), you could even have all requests served by always-on backends

Comment: Basically I want to reserve some instances which act like backends. GAE should still do the load balancing but users should hit a long running instance all the time. Maybe this means I do not want GAE to scale dynamically at all in my testing environment.